# Single sign on not working for non admin users in WSO identity server version 5.1.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Single sign on not working for non admin users in WSO2 identity server version 5.1.0. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your questions is not detailed enough to understand the issue. Explain the issue with step you followed.

Comment: I have two applications sharing single signon using WSO2IS. I logged in to one of my application and try to open my second application in another browser tab. It is not working. But the peculiar thing is when i try to login through the user which is created while creating tenant it is working fine. It is not working for the users which are created after that.

Answer (score 0):

Are both service providers created in the same tenant ? If not SSO would not work because the user is authenticated only in one tenant not the other. However if the other service provider is set as a SAAS app, then cross tenant authentication is supported.

Comment: I have multiple tenants with multiple users. SSO is working for the users which have admin rights. Not working for other users.